# Read current php page and write source to mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, file

I am running a html file with the following php function called from a different file:

```
<?php include('Other.php'); ?>
<?php ReadMe("http://www.mysite.com/".basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])); ?>
```

I have all the code working but the problem is it writes out 30 records instead of just one:

```
ReadMe($file)
{
$html = file_get_contents($file);
$link = mysql_connect("db.com", "user", "password");
mysql_select_db("Code");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Code (Html) VALUES('$html')");
}
```

Ok, this seems simple enough but the problem is that 30 records are created, it seems that when the first (html) page is read by the other.php file it executes the php code it is reading thus iterating to write out 30 records? How can I avoid this??!

Comment: Why are you using a URL instead of a local file name?  What's the goal here?  Is it a HTML file, or a PHP file?

Comment: The html file is on the server I am trying to read the source code and write it to the database.

Comment: Yes it sounds simple because your are loading the current script in the current script. So you have an endless loop there. Try loading any other URL, it should work just fine.

Comment: Okay, pass the filename to ReadMe.  It looks like you have a script, which passes its own URL, and downloads/executes its self in recursion.  So, change the argument to the HTML file; like `ReadMe('something.html'`.

Comment: It only works for loading a different page but I need to read the current page to get the source of it into the database.

Comment: I have to be able to distinguish when the file is actually opened on the server versus when I am reading it using file_get_contents() so I don't execute it when it is just trying to read it into a string....

Comment: I figure I can use $_SESSION variables to set a session variable before the code is executed then change so that before the file is read it isn't continuously read? I'm not sure...